# Sanity check with Bolzano's theorem: Does $c\in[a;b]$ or $c\in(a;b)$?

Tags: proof-verification, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

Bolzano's theorem, either a lemma or a corollary of the intermediate value theorem, states pretty simply that

> If a function $y=f(x)$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a;b]$, and when $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have opposite signs, then there exists a $c\in(a;b)$ such that $f(c)=0.$

However, every [now](http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/IntValueTheorem13.htm) and [again](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/limcon/limcon06/limcon06.html), one might find the alternative statement $c\in[a;b]$. Even Wikipedia is inconsistent; the main thread of the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Theorem) is fine with the open interval while the page on the [least upper bound property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property#Intermediate_value_theorem) explicitly gives $[a;b].$

Certainly, if Bolzano's theorem holds for $(a;b)$ then for $[a;b]$ the result follows immediately. But the opposite is not true, hence the sanity check.

It is obvious from a commonsense standpoint that the interval should be open, that is $c\in(a;b)$. The problem is thus rigorously proving my intuition. I do not think graphical thinking ought to do it since the reasoning might be circular.

As a final point, the answer may lie in some axiom of real numbers. Sadly, I am not terribly fluent in real analysis to figure it out on my own.

**Which is necessary, $(a;b)$ or $[a;b]$?** $\leftarrow$ TL; DR

---

MathWorld, an Internet encyclopedia sponsored by Wolfram Alpha, gives the interval as **closed**. See [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntermediateValueTheorem.html).

[Brouwer's fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#One-dimensional_case), whose one-dimensional case implies a special case of the intermediate value theorem, claims the interval is, too, $[a;b]$.

Comment: \*crawls back into his hole when the answer is a one-sentence comment\*

Comment: Since $f(a)f(b)<0$ by hypothesis, $c\ne a$ and $c\ne b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have opposite signs, then $f(a)\not=0\not=f(b)$ - so saying that $f$ has a zero in $[a, b]$ is equivalent to saying that $f$ has a zero in $(a, b)$.

Comment: lol, fsr I was looking for the answer in the completeness axiom :|

Comment: Pretty obvious but there are two versions: $f(a)f(b)<0$ implies $c\in (a,b)$ and $f(a)f(b)\leq 0$ implies $c\in [a,b]$.